# ErrorLoadingRVMRC - rvmrc file is not trusted when running passenger for Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, passenger

I've been hacking at this thing for hours now and suddenly its 4am and I am no further.

It is a rails 3 application.

I have cap deploy working, I have a gemset, the site is deployed, bundle has installed the gems I need into the gemset.  I have installed passenger.  I am running on a multiuser RVM.

I have done `passenger start` but it is giving me this error about not being trusted:

```
The rvmrc located in '/var/www/html/xx/releases/20111212035754' 
could not be loaded, likely due to trust mechanisms. Please run 'rvm rvmrc 
{trust,untrust} "/var/www/html/xx/releases/20111212035754"' to 
continue, or set rvm_trust_rvmrcs_flag to 1. (RVM::ErrorLoadingRVMRC)
```

I tried:

- Setting rvm_trust_rvmrcs_flag to 1 in .rvmrc
- Running the specified command
- Upgrading rvm to head
- Upgrading rvm to latest
- Added the setup_load_paths.rb file
- Generated .rvmrc with `rvm use 1.9.3@captor --create --rvmrc`

I am at wits end now. I've pasted my config files/output [here](https://gist.github.com/1467942) and would be elated if someone found a typo :)

It shouldn't be this hard should it?  What am I missing?

I thought it was related to [this](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/560) but the issue is closed now.

Answer (score 5):

My first recommendation would be to move the .rvmrc file up a couple folders to `'/var/www/html/xx`. From there it will be effective for all sub directories and will continue to be used without change across deploys.  [This page](http://itshouldbeuseful.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/deploying-with-capistrano-and-rvm-rvmrc-trust-issues/) has a different solution that might work in your case, but I don't think even that is necessary if the .rvmrc file is moved up.

Next, when you say you tried "Running the specified command", what exactly did you run? I believe what you need to run is, `rvm rvmrc trust /path/to/where` your .rvmrc is at.

I hope that helps.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried them still nothing :( Must be something funny with my setup.  I'll try getting rid of all gem/sets/rubies and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried running ``rvm rvmrc trust .rvmrc `` inside the project folder and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably related to this bug: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/560

What I've done (today) is get latest version of RVN to get it fixed:

```
 rvm get latest
 rvm reload
```